# windows 8 nx (xd) enabling support for HP compaq D530

Tags: windows-8, nx, hp

I try to install win8 on HP D530 SFF... but after installation it hungs on error 0x000005d - which means no sse2, PAE or NX support - after investigation:

```
x86 Family 15 Model 6 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel

NX              -       Supports no-execute page protection
PAE             *       Supports > 32-bit physical addresses
SSE2            *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 2
```

of course HP BIOS is more than ascetic...

Is there any possibility to turn on NX (XD BIT) - how?

Comment: Oh, sorry i was so tired so i'm put it wrong place...

Answer (score 1):

About the only way (if it is possible) is to use the BIOS setup and see if there is an option that will enable/disable the NX bit.